# loop a range() Function with a time delay- Python

Tags: python

How to loop a range() Function  x number of times with a time delay in Python?
for example, for i in range(4,9) repeat  it for 3 times and each time stop 5 second before starting the new count. The answer should be like this:

```
"0 second delay"  (4,5,6,7,8,9)
"5 second delay"  (4,5,6,7,8,9)
"10 second delay"  (4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
from time import sleep
N = 3  # number of times you want to repeat
for d in xrange(N):
    sleep(d * 5)  
    for x in xrange(4, 10):
        # do something
```

**Note**: Assuming Python 2.x (xrange) otherwise, you should use the regular range (Python 3.x).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `time` module. It is a really handy tool when wanting to wait before print statements. `time.sleep(x)` pauses  the script for "x" amount of seconds.

```
import time

list = []
for _ in range(3):
    time.sleep(5)
    for i in range(4, 9):
        list.append(i)
        print(i)
```